# Flutter - ListView.Builder - Horizontal scroll not working

Tags: flutter, listview, horizontal-scrolling

When I set scrollDirection equal Axis.horizontal, scrolling did not work.
Please help me to changes my code to work properly?
When I set scrollDirection equal Axis.vertical, it work correctly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50),
        height: 100,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
        color: Colors.red[400],
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (c, i) {
            return Text('Item ${i + 1} ');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Explain your question/situation little bit further. Provide the console error of where it's not scroll-able.

Answer (score 0):

`Axis.vertical` is working because you have provided the parent a height. For `Aix.horizontal` to work you need to provide the parent Container a width. Check the code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50),
        width: 150,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
        color: Colors.red[400],
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (c, i) {
            return Text('Item ${i + 1} ');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I copy and paste your code and test in browser, android and windows desktop app but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer Below Code. It's working for me. Please check once.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50),
          height: 100,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
          color: Colors.red[400],
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: 50,
            itemBuilder: (c, i) {
              return Text('Item ${i + 1} ');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and get this results. Android Device: worked / Windows Desktop: did not work / Chrome Browser: did not work but in Developer tools (enable Toggle device toolbar) worked. I want to enable scrolling in any device.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give width for parent container like below, just add a width, base on the direction you always need to provide height or width.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50),
        height: 100,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
        color: Colors.red[400],
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (c, i) {
            return Text('Item ${i + 1} ');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in order for the scroll to work for all platforms, you need to do what is written in the article
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Card(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("$item"),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        // etc.
      };
}
```